# Adon 'Olam or Yigdal after Ma'ariv Friday night and Yom Tov?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, prayer-book

In many Siddurim and Maḥzorim Adon 'Olam is printed at the end of Ma'ariv for Friday night and Yom Tov. But in my experience, the vast majority of (Ashkenazi) Shuls sing Yigdal at this point instead. Why do some (Ashkenazi) Shuls recite Adon 'Olam after Ma'ariv and some (most?) recite Yigdal?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it.

Comment: I have also been in synagogues where both were sung.

Comment: I've been in some shuls that do adon olam regularly and other shuls that leave it up to the sha"tz which they do.

Comment: Interesting. I've only been in one that has done it, and only on Rosh HaShanah.

Comment: In light of the comments, I've changed the question a bit.

Comment: Where I grew up it was Yigdal on plain Friday night and Adon Olam on every Yom Tov.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86640/5275