# Origin of saying Adon Olam or Yigdal at end of prayers

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, synagogue, maariv, musaf

In many Nusach Ashkenaz shuls, there is a minhag to say [either Adon Olam or Yigdal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18442/5275) at the end of Shabbat / Yom Tov *Ma'ariv* and many say *Adon Olam* at the end of Musaph.

What's the reason / origin of this custom?

Comment: Almost dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18442/adon-olam-or-yigdal-after-maariv-friday-night-and-yom-tov

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting part in *The Encyclopedia of Jewish Prayer: The Ashkenazic and Sephardic Rites* (p. 7) citing [*Mateh Moshe*](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%98) ל"א ([p. 71 in this edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/40439)). Regarding the general recital of Adon Olam, he says that all those, who sing it with much devotion, prevent the Satan to defy their prayers, while based on [Mishlei 16:7,](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2816.htm#7) their enemies will fall. At the end we sing it for the following reason (see again *Mateh Moshe* רי"ו on [p. 118](http://hebrewbooks.org/40439)):

> Just as *Bereishit* is reread immediately after concluding all Five Books of the Pentateuch on *Simhat Torah, Adon Olam* is repeated in similar manner at the conclusion of a service so that Satan shall not be a threat.

Comment: Not quite ready to accept this answer. Does he suggest doing this at the end of **every** prayer? If so, then it seems the prevalent minhag is to say it only on Shabbat / Yom Tov. Perhaps it was not said on weekdays because of torach tzibbur?

Comment: @DanF Indeed, it is discussed among the general weekday rules of prayer in Mateh Moshe. I need to look around a bit, but most probably it was avoided not to burden the congregation, especially on weekdays, when everyone is in hurry.