# Why do we sing Adon Olam at the end of Tefila in Shabbat whereas in regular day before it?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, nusach-sefard

What is the difference between saying Adon Olam at the end of Tefila and its start? Why do we sing Adon Olam at the end of Tefila in Shabbat whereas in regular day before it?

Comment: Is it not recited at the beginning on Shabbat too?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86640/origin-of-saying-adon-olam-or-yigdal-at-end-of-prayers

Comment: In Frankfurt a/M, the custom was to begin shacharit every day with אדון עולם and it would not be appended at the end, except for ma'ariv on Yom Kippur (also not shacharit)